# Determine alias used when tomcat keystore was created

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat8

I need to determine the alias used when a tomcat keystore was created using `keytool -keysize 2048 -genkey -alias <***> -keyalg RSA -keystore <***>`

Keystore was created by an installation script and now I have to create a certificate signing request (csr) for it, but to do that, I need the alias used.

Comment: Assuming you know the filename, run `keytool -list -keystore thefilename`. You must supply the same password as was used on creation, except for Java 8 or lower (which default to JKS, not PKCS12 as newer versions do) you _can_ just hit return and `-list` will work with a warning. But your subsequent `-certreq` will definitely need the password(s) -- keystore password always, and key password if different.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I did try running a -list, however all I saw was a list of the certs and their aliases - what I need is the alias of the keystore itself.  Is it somewhere in the output of -list and I just missed it?

Comment: There is no such thing as the alias of the keystore itself.

Comment: Yes, eventually I figured that out.  Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find what looked like the installation script and deduce the alias from it.  Thanks again for your help.